# Java: trying to convert an int value to a String

Tags: java, string, int, primitive

In my method `format(int n)` I am simply trying to return the passed int value as a string. using the `toString()` method.

```
public String format(int n) {

    return n.toString();
}
```

However, I keep getting the error `int cannot be dereferenced`. From what I understand, this is happening because I am treating a primitive int value as if it were an object, but I do not know how to fix it. I would appreciate any help with this.

Comment: `return "" + n;`

Comment: primitive types such as `int` are not objects and so do not have methods. You can use `String.valueOf(n)`.

Comment: I just posted an answer and noticed that @MuratK. already posted the same one :D

Answer (score 8):

You cannot invoke methods on primitives.
You could box `int` to `Integer` and invoke `toString()` on that :

```
return ((Integer)n).toString();
```

Thanks to autoboxing you could even directly rewrite your method by replacing `int` with `Integer` :

```
public String format(Integer n) {    
    return n.toString();
}
```

And invoking it in this way (the compiler will box `int` for you  to `Integer` as the parameter is passed) :

```
int x = ...;
format(x);
```

But a simpler way is using the `String.valueOf(int)` method :

```
public String format(int n) {
    return String.valueOf(n);
}
```

In this case, is it really needed to create a method that just delegates to `String.valueOf()` ?

Answer (score 0):

You could also concatenate the int with the empty String like this:

```
public String format(int n) {
    return "" + n;
}
```

Under the hood this ends up calling String.valueOf(n) and uses a StringBuilder to append the two together, but modern compilers will optimize that out for you so it is not a performance trade off.